# Templates on dynamic segments

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I have a requirement to make what is essentially a dynamic form (wizard) that has multiple steps. Now I want to be able to quickly add new steps to the wizard in the future (or remove them) so I don;t to create separate routes for each step like so:

```
this.resource('wizard', { path: '/' }, function() {
  this.route('step1', { path: '/' });
  this.route('step2');
  this.route('step3');
  this.route('step4');
  this.route('step5');
});
```

I would much prefer to have a dynamic segment that takes in the name of the step and loads the corresponding template of the same name, like so

```
this.resource('wizard', { path: '/' }, function() {
  this.route('step', { path: '/:step' });
});
```

Is this at all possible or is this just wishful thinking.

Comment: Keep in mind making them into a single route with a dynamic segment will disable the back button

Comment: That is a very good point. Thanks

Comment: I would use a query parameter for the step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with a solution but I am not sure it is considered the best...

I have defined a route in the router to take in a dynamic segment with the name of the template:

```
this.resource('wizard', { path: '/wizard' }, function() {
  this.route('missing', { path: '/:step' });
});
```

I have then created a missing route that takes this dynamic segment from the model and uses it to load in the template into the appropriate outlet

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function(controller, model) {
    this.render('wizard/' + model.step, {
      controller: controller
    });
  }
});
```

I would love to hear some thoughts on this solution.